# Silverlight 4 sending client Exceptions through WCF, best practices

Tags: silverlight, exception

I am trying to find the best way to pass client exceptions for logging purposes. I found this so question: [Serializing Exceptions WCF + Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979236/serializing-exceptions-wcf-silverlight)

I was thinking of going that route. I had tried sending the Exception object, but that did not work. I also notice that the Exception class in silverlight does not hold all of the properties that it normally has outside of silverlight (but I guess that's something else). Is this the best way to go about it? Serialize my Exception and send that through WCF? Any helpful links and/or questions would be much appreciated (I already have classes/wrappers for a custom binary serializer via http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/03c16f90-6745-44c6-8d83-f768d09949de/silverlight-2-doing-data-part-vii-custom-binary-serialization.aspx)

I just want to reiterate that it's an Exception from the client to the db, not a fault exception from a WCF call. I have found a lot of information on that already. Thanks in advance.